# How to select my bootstrap navbar links for proper positioning?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a bootstrap navbar, and I have been previously selecting the links with a span class of "nav-text".  This is working for the font-size and color, but when I try applying a margin or padding I can not get a response.  I have tried selecting the links for positioning in many, many different ways now so I've turned here.

Here is the html:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

    <li><a href="physicians.php"><span class="nav-text">Physicians</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="location.php"><span class="nav-text">Directions</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="services.php"><span class="nav-text">Services</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="faq.php"><span class="nav-text">FAQ</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="privacy.php"><span class="nav-text">Privacy</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="health.php"><span class="nav-text">Health Links</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="policy.php"><span class="nav-text">Office Policy</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://webview.mckesson.com/####/"><span class="nav-text" id="view">W***** Login</span></a></li>
  </ul>
```

So how would I give the .nav-text links proper positioning?  I was succesful in giving the #view id link a padding left.  But the padding top doesn't work for that either?

Here is the entire navbar if you need it (bootstrap)

```
<header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="#" id="logo"></a>
</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

    <li><a href="physicians.php"><span class="nav-text">Physicians</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="location.php"><span class="nav-text">Directions</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="services.php"><span class="nav-text">Services</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="faq.php"><span class="nav-text">FAQ</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="privacy.php"><span class="nav-text">Privacy</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="health.php"><span class="nav-text">Health Links</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="policy.php"><span class="nav-text">Office Policy</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://webview.mckesson.com/mvfpi/"><span class="nav-text" id="webview">Webview Login</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
</header>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ek6v1p0z/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add padding/margin to your links use:

```
.nav li a {
    padding: 45px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

For example.

Your updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ek6v1p0z/2/)